# facing weblogic.application.ModuleException: null Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, gradle, migration, weblogic12c

I am trying to converting spring mvc maven project to gradle(version 6.7.1) project using init command method, after converting the project and modified the respected dependency in build.gradle file and iam trying to run the project with the weblogic server 12c facing the below error in eclipse console log

```
<BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1228807251454800" for task "1". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: null
    null"
    weblogic.application.ModuleException: null
    null
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.createModuleException(WebAppModule.java:1824)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:270)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:682)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:98)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:41)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.polulateOneClassInfo(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:240)
        at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.populateClassInfos(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:193)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    > 

<Dec 22, 2020 6:04:28 PM IST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "degrees".> 
<Dec 22, 2020 6:04:28 PM IST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
```

folder structure below:
[project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O61Bf.png)

Comment: Please give suggestion on this issue, thanks for the advance

Comment: Did it run successfully in weblogic when you were using maven?

Comment: Assuming it worked before, it is probably a versioning issue with third-party libraries in the war/ear. You could take a look at the generated artifact from the Maven build and compare it to the Gradle one (and inspect it to see if there are any differences in which jar files are bundled).

Comment: @tgdavies yeah project worked fine before with maven

Comment: @BjørnVester yeah it worked before, will check it on the any version related impact are there or any jar issues in the migrated gradle build and confirm thanks

Comment: I tired lower version of gradle 5.4 and run the project , now no error comming in console, but the page is going 404

Comment: The above 404 issue is due to folder structure is diferrent from the expectation of the gradle format, now I have customized the folder structure in build gradle using sourceset, now project is running by identifying src file which is mentioned in build.gradle, But now facing another issue Failed to configure WTP for project, am checking on it

Comment: which version of weblogic and java are you using ? (java 7?)

Comment: @devwebcl java version 1.8 and oracle weblogic server 12c(12.1.3)

Comment: Thanks All for your time, now I have closed the project and reopened agained ran it, the converted gradle project works fine now, running on server and able to see the local project page in browser , thanks all

Comment: I have removed the pom.xml as well after that reopened the project and ran it